# How does the new keyword make a difference?

Tags: c++, pointers, nodes, new-operator

```cpp
class sortedList
{
    class Node
    {
        public:
            int value;
            Node* next;

            Node()
            {
                this->value = 0;
                this->next = NULL;
            }
            Node(int value)
            {
                this->value = value;
                this->next = NULL;
            } 
    }* head = NULL, * tail = NULL;

    public:
        void addNode(int value)
        {
            Node* n = Node(value);
            //More code...
        }
};
```

Why does adding `new` before `Node(value)` make the code correct?
I think the code above should stay wrong because pointer doesn't equal a node.

Comment: `=` means assignment, not comparison.

Comment: adding the `new` makes it more like `(new Node)(value)`, not `new (Node(value))` like you seem to think. It's a completely different expression, not a unary operand applied to the same sub-expression.

Comment: `Node(value)` returns a `Node`, but `new Node(value)` returns a pointer to a `Node`.

Comment: [Prefer](https://arne-mertz.de/2015/12/modern-c-features-nullptr/) `nullptr` to `NULL`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not valid code:

```
Node* n = Node(value);
```

The reason `new` makes it work is that `new` returns a pointer.

You can either declare your `Node` using dynamic storage:

```
Node* n = new Node(value);
```

or automatic storage:

```
Node n(value);
```

Comment: Please don't peddle this "heap"/"stack" stuff

Comment: Do you prefer "dynamic" and "automatic" instead? If so I'll edit accordingly

Comment: @CoryKramer yes, that would be better. Those are the terms the standard uses. The stack and heap are how compiler vendors *implement* those terms

Comment: @RemyLebeau Possibly :)

Comment: @CoryKramer Ta :P

Answer (score 4):

`Node(value)` is a temporary value of type `Node`. `Node* n` is a variable of type `Node*`. You're attempting to initialise an object of type `Node*` with an argument of type `Node`. These types are not implicitly convertible to one another, so the program is ill-formed.

The result of `new T` is `T*`. So, result of `new Node(value)` is a `Node*`. An object of type `Node*` can be initialised with an argument of type `Node*`.